# Mailchimp form embed with Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, mailchimp

I'm wanting to create a responsive Mailchimp embed form with Bootstrap. I embedded the form but it's not responsive. It's only an issue for mobile devices. I want to be able to make the submit bottom go below the email input for mobile devices and both of these fields to be centred.

[image]

http://www.bootply.com/7wn9vHDFdw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this to your css Elliott

```
@media (max-width:768px){
    #mc_embed_signup .clear {clear:none; display:block !important;}
}
```

Now the signup and the button will be on separate lines as well as centered. You can then add custom margins and paddings to the signup box and the button without a problem.

Comment: Thanks but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: There was a small syntax error with the previous version.... The above edited code should work fine now :)

Comment: Thanks that worked but for some reason the email input and submit button don't want to centre properly. They are more offset to the right.

Comment: I think it could be because of some other css property that you added somewhere else. Do send me a jsfiddle and I will help you fix it asap :)